# How to increase position offsets in a lucene index to correspond to <p> tags?

Tags: html, tags, lucene, indexing, position

I am using Lucene 3.0.3. In preparation to using SpanQuery and PhraseQuery, I would like to mark paragraph boundaries in my index in a way that will discourage these queries from matching across paragraph boundaries. I understand that I need to increment position by some suitably large value in the `PositionIncrementAttribute` when processing text to mark paragraph boundaries. Let's assume that in the source document, my paragraph boundaries are marked by `<p>...</p>` pairs.

How do I set up my token stream to detect the tags?  Also, I don't actually want to index the tags themselves. For the purposes of indexing, I would rather increment the position of the next legitimate token, rather than emitting a token that corresponds to the tag, since I don't want it to affect search.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to add gaps (= PositionIncrement > 1) is to provide a custom TokenStream. You do not need to change your Analyzer for that. However, HTML parsing should be done upstream (i.e., you should segment and clean your input text accordingly before feeding it to Lucene).

Here is a full, working example (imports omitted):

```
public class GapTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Directory dir = new RAMDirectory();
        final IndexWriterConfig iwConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_4_10_1, new SimpleAnalyzer());
        final IndexWriter iw = new IndexWriter(dir, iwConfig);

        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new TextField("body", "A B C", Store.YES));
        doc.add(new TextField("body", new PositionIncrementTokenStream(10)));
        doc.add(new TextField("body", "D E F", Store.YES));

        System.out.println(doc);
        iw.addDocument(doc);
        iw.close();

        final IndexReader ir = DirectoryReader.open(dir);
        IndexSearcher is = new IndexSearcher(ir);

        QueryParser qp = new QueryParser("body", new SimpleAnalyzer());

        for (String q : new String[] { "\"A B C\"", "\"A B C D\"",
                "\"A B C D\"", "\"A B C D\"~10", "\"A B C D E F\"~10",
                "\"A B C D F E\"~10", "\"A B C D F E\"~11" }) {
            Query query = qp.parse(q);
            TopDocs docs = is.search(query, 10);
            System.out.println(docs.totalHits + "\t" + q);
        }
        ir.close();
    }

    /**
     * A gaps-only TokenStream (uses {@link PositionIncrementAttribute}
     * 
     * @author Christian Kohlschuetter
     */
    private static final class PositionIncrementTokenStream extends TokenStream {
    private boolean first = true;
    private PositionIncrementAttribute attribute;
    private final int positionIncrement;

    public PositionIncrementTokenStream(final int positionIncrement) {
        super();
        this.positionIncrement = positionIncrement;
        attribute = addAttribute(PositionIncrementAttribute.class);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
        if (first) {
            first = false;
            attribute.setPositionIncrement(positionIncrement);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void reset() throws IOException {
        super.reset();
        first = true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks @Christian. This is interesting. I hadn't thought of this approach of segmenting the text first, and then introducing the gaps. This could certainly be used to build up a more principled document parser. I had taken a more brute-force approach and created a variant of the `StandardTokenizer` based on a modified jflex file, into which I inserted a rule to detect paragraphs: `MARKUP    = ("<" {ALPHANUM}+ {ANY}* ">" | "</" {ALPHANUM}+ {ANY}* ">") ` and `ANY = ({ALPHANUM} | {WHITESPACE} | [\"='&;])`. Of course my approach is more brittle, but it seems to work well on my TREC documents.

Comment: @Gene. Yup, tokenizing at HTML level might work at a first glance but opens up a bunch of problems that will be revealed only when it's too late ;-)

Comment: @Gene. What might be useful here is to use [boilerpipe](http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/) with a KeepEverythingExtractor. This already provides you some segmentation that can be used as input for the suggested solution above.

Comment: By the way, a simpler way to introduce this gap without a custom tokenstream is to implement Analyzer.getPositionIncrementGap() to return the gap that you want... its designed specifically for this purpose.

Comment: @Robert Thanks! When I build a document parser that preserves sentence/paragraph structure, I will definitely use this approach to delimit to the various pieces.

Comment: @Robert what pattern should I use to have getPositionIncrementGap() return different values depending on the text being added? Calls to Document.add() just buffer the fields without any processing, so the context that might determine gap size is lost.